# Attempting to update results generated from a while loop

Tags: php

My main issue that I am running into is basically this:

I have a while loop that generates results from a query. With the results that have been generated, I want the ability to update the table the original query was from.

The query produces the expected results, but the table is not being updated when I click the REMOVE button. I am also trying to find a solution for the results to be updated after the UPDATE query executes...

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE sold='n' ORDER BY year DESC";

    $query = mysql_query($sql);


    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 

    echo 
    "       
        <tr>
            <td style='border-bottom-style:dotted;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;font-size:.9em'>",$row['year'],"</td>
            <td style='border-bottom-style:dotted;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;font-size:.9em'>",$row['make'],"</td>
            <td style='border-bottom-style:dotted;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;font-size:.9em'>",$row['model'],"</td>
            <td style='border-bottom-style:dotted;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;font-size:.9em'><input type='submit' name='remove' value='REMOVE' style='background-color:#C33;color:white;padding:10px;border-radius:5px;width:70px'/></td>
        </tr>";

    if(isset($_POST['remove'])){
        $removeSql = "UPDATE `table`.`vehicles` SET `display`='0' WHERE `vin`='{$row['vin']}'";
        mysql_query($removeSql) or die('check that code dummy');
    }

    }
    mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: That's a submit button, will not work without form tag. You can't do it this way.

Comment: You can write the remove code on a separate page and convert that submit button to normal button and pass `vin` id on click of that button and call that page using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

That's a submit button, will not work without form tag. You can't do it this way.

You can write the `remove code` on a separate page and convert that `submit button` to `normal button` and pass `vin id` on `click` of that `button` and `call` that page using `ajax`.

Or if you don't know `ajax` and want to do it on that page itself then do it this way :

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE sold='n' ORDER BY year DESC";

$query = mysql_query($sql);


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 

echo 
"       
    <tr>
        <td style='border-bottom-style:dotted;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;font-size:.9em'>",$row['year'],"</td>
        <td style='border-bottom-style:dotted;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;font-size:.9em'>",$row['make'],"</td>
        <td style='border-bottom-style:dotted;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;font-size:.9em'>",$row['model'],"</td>
        <td style='border-bottom-style:dotted;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;font-size:.9em'>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="vin_id" value="<?php echo $row['vin']; ?>">
            <input type='submit' name='remove' value='REMOVE' style='background-color:#C33;color:white;padding:10px;border-radius:5px;width:70px'/>
        </form></td>
    </tr>";

}

if(isset($_POST['remove'])){
    $removeSql = "UPDATE `table`.`vehicles` SET `display`='0' WHERE `vin`='".$_POST['vin_id']."'";
    mysql_query($removeSql) or die('check that code dummy');
}

mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! I will try that later when I get a chance. I was wondering if it was absolutely necessary for the `input` to be within a `form`. It sounds like I may need to look into `ajax` as well.